# Overwrite object method in javascript

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have an object with callback-method which I should extend.
The object is `elementHandle` and method `onCheckURLDone(result, data)` is called internally somewhere. I need to execute some extended code and call back original function code. 
I tried something like this:

```
  var cachedCallback = elementHandle.onCheckURLDone;

  elementHandle.onCheckURLDone = (function(result, data){
    console.log("Some extended code...");

    return function(result, data) {
        return cachedCallback.apply(elementHandle, arguments);
    }
  });
```

But original code is not called here. What's wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `return function()...` line and the close brace corresponding to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var cachedCallback = elementHandle.onCheckURLDone;
elementHandle.onCheckURLDone = function (result, data) {
    console.log('Some extended code...');
    return cachedCallback.apply(elementHandle, arguments);
};
```

Original callback in your code is called inside returned function. So if you want it to be executed, you have to call it like this:

```
elementHandle.onCheckURLDone(someResult, someDate)(someResult, someDate);
```

I suppose it is not what you want.

Comment: "try this" answers are not usually useful, there's almost *always* something useful to say rather than just dumping out code.

Comment: It was easy, don't know why I wrote that return wrapper :) Thank you